# Symfony / Doctrine Mapping many to many , getting ArrayColletion

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, many-to-many

i'm having some problems getting the items for two Entities relation.
There are three tables. Terceiros - rel_terceiros_flags - Flags. 
Terceiros have many flags.
And Flags can have many Terceiros.

Right now , im only using two Entities : Terceiros & Flags. The relacional table is not mapped in orm entity.

On Terceiros Entity :

```
/**
 * Many Users have Many Groups.
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Flags")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="rel_terceiros_flags",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_sage", referencedColumnName="id_sage")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_flag", referencedColumnName="id_flag")}
 *      )
 */
private $flagsTer;

/**
 * Terceiros constructor.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->flagsTer = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getFlagsTer()
{
    return $this->flagsTer;
}
```

And when I go render the object from Terceiros search by id, the ArrayColletion comes empty. I have 3 rows on relational table with 3 flags for the same Terceiro. When i do the Dump i get something like this:

```
#collection: ArrayCollection {#2463 ▼
  -elements: []
}
```

On Controller:

```
/**
 * SubGrid Example
 *
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\LogicException
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\AlreadySubmittedException
 * @throws \LogicException
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 *
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Route("/terceiros/example",options={"expose"=true}, name="app_terceiros_example")
 * @throws \LogicException
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function terFlagsAction(Request $request)
{

    $terceirosRepos = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Terceiros');
    $terceiros = $terceirosRepos->find('00001');
    return $this->render(':app/terceiros:terceiros_flags.html.twig',['terceiros' => $terceiros]);
}
```

On Twig view:

`{{ dump(terceiros) }}`

Can you help me?

Comment: What query are you using to retrieve your `Terceiros` entity? What did you use to get the dump of the `ArrayCollection` shown at the end of your message?

Comment: Sorry for dont being specific, im dumping Terceiros Object on Twig like this 
{{ dump(user) }}

Comment: Question Edited , check now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
dump($terceiros->getFlagsTer()->getValues());
```

Comment: Sorry for not being specific , im dumping the Terceiros object on Twig like this 
{{ dump(user) }}

Comment: Question Edited , check now :)

Comment: Thanks! It worked!!!!  #collection: ArrayCollection {#3518 ▼
      -elements: array:4 [▼
        0 => Flags {#3528 ▶}
        1 => Flags {#3530 ▶}
        2 => Flags {#3531 ▶}
        3 => Flags {#3532 ▶}

Comment: cool! Due to lazy loading? Can @pedro fix with some loading annotation?

Comment: I just didnt understand why do we need to copulate the ArrayColletion with the dump.